# $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ P [ \|a+Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]}{ P [ \|Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]}$ where $Z \in R^n$ is i.i.d Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How to find the limit
\begin{align}
 \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ P [ \|a+Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]}{ P [ \|Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]}
\end{align}
where  $a= (2  \sqrt{n},0,0,..)$ where $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is standard i.i.d. Gaussian.

Note that  $P [ \|Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]= \frac{\gamma \left(n/2,\frac{(1+\epsilon)^2 n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(n/2 \right)}$. So, we have to compute $P [ \|a+Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]$.

Using a proview result here I was able to determine that 
\begin{align}
P [ \|a+Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}]= E \left[ 1_{Q \le (1+\epsilon)^2 n} \left( \Phi \left( \sqrt{(1+\epsilon)^2n-Q}-a\right)-\Phi \left( -\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)^2n-Q}-a\right) \right)   \right]
\end{align}
where $Q$ is chi-squre of degree $n-1$.

However, now this integral is not very easy to compute?

Is there a faster way of finding this limit?

I also tried to Markov inequalit
\begin{align}
P [ \|a+Z\| \le (1+\epsilon) \sqrt{n}] \le 
\frac{E[ \|Z+a\|^2}{ (1+\epsilon)^2 n}=\frac{5}{(1+\epsilon)^2}
\end{align}
but it appears that Markov inequlity is not very tight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\epsilon > 0$, the denominator can be written as $$P[Z_1^2 + Z_2^2 + \cdots Z_n^2 \leq (1 + \epsilon)^2 n].$$

Since $Z_i^2$ are i.i.d. of mean $1$, the strong law of large numbers tells us that this converges to $1$.  Squaring the inside of the numerator and dividing by $n$ gives that the numerator equals $$P\left[(2 - Z_1/\sqrt{n})^2 + \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 / n \leq (1 + \epsilon)^2 \right].$$

We know that $(2 - Z_1 /\sqrt{n})^2$ converges almost surely to $4$, and by the strong law $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 / n$ converges almost surely to $1$.  Therefore, if $(1+\epsilon)^2 > 5$ then the numerator converges to $1$; if $(1 + \epsilon)^2 < 5$ the numerator converges to $0$.  If $(1+\epsilon)^2 = 5$ then the central limit theorem says that the numerator converges to $1/2.$

Comment: How fast does it go to zero for $(1+\epsilon)^2<5$?

Comment: @Boby, I'm not entirely sure, but I think exponentially quickly, since $P[\sum_{i =1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 / n < (1 + \delta)]$ goes to $1$ exponentially quickly as does $P[(2 - Z_1/\sqrt{n})^2 < 4(1 + \delta)]$; the first is from large deviations, the latter is because Gaussian tails are like $e^{-x^2}/x$.

Comment: Can I actually split the the sum $P[ (2-Z_1/\sqrt{n})^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Z_i^2/n ]$ into sum of probabilities ?

Comment: @Boby, Basically, yes, with a union bound.  Let's label $a=(2 - Z_1/\sqrt{n})^2$ and $b = \sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} Z_i^2 / n$.  Note that if $a + b \leq (1  + \epsilon)^2$, then either $a < (4/5)(1 + \epsilon)^2$ or $b < (1/5)(1 + \epsilon)^2$.  This means that $P[a + b \leq (1 + \epsilon)^2] \leq P[a \leq (4/5)(1 + \epsilon)^2] + P[b \leq (1/5)(1 + \epsilon)^2].$